# django Google calendar v3 insert event - parse error

Tags: python, django, rest, google-calendar-api

I'm not using client libraries but REST directly. I have succesfully created google login. I save user's access_token. I use access_token (here in this code is hardcoded) when I try to create new event and insert it in user's calendar. Here is my code

```
def google_get_list(request):
    parser = httplib2.Http()
    uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}"\
        .format(YOUR_API_KEY='AIzaSyD_Axx9SGH0Y71xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    params = urllib.urlencode({
        "summary": "Test Calendar",
    })
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
               'Authorization':  'Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQdFo8IXu5gAns8qEiyLbcbZxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
               'X-JavaScript-User-Agent':  'Google APIs Explorer'
               }
    resp, content = parser.request(uri, method='POST', body=params, headers=headers)
    print content
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

content that is received (print) is

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: is the `body=params` valid?

Comment: How could I check that? I'm assuming that body is a problem.. but don't know how to fix it

Comment: params here would evaluate to `"summary=Test Calendar",` which i guess is the problem.

Comment: Do you know how should it be formulated?

Comment: well. I havent used it extensively, but just looking at the API, looks like body might not be a required field. Just try body=None, and send the params part of `uri`

Comment: if i set body=None... then content received is `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  ...
  <p>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>`

Comment: I was refering to this example: https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/browse/python2/httplib2/test/functional/test_proxies.py - (No body parameter)

Comment: I don't understand how could this example help me. I should reproduce this request Request

 
`POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZRQycAWqXwg85fLmQ8Yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
 
{
 "end": {
  "date": "2013-05-28"
 },
 "start": {
  "date": "2013-05-27"
 }
}`

Comment: that's based on https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30785/discussion-between-klonitklonit-and-karthikr)